# Why does arithmetic operations on (more than) three unsigned chars always trigger a warning when using -Wconversion?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Compiling the following code

```
// foo.c

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

int main() {
    uint8_t a = 1;
    uint8_t b = 10;
    uint8_t c = 12;

    uint8_t k = a + b + c;
}
```

using GCC 11.2 (also other GCC versions) with the following full-command:

```
gcc -Wconversion foo.c
```

Results in the following warning:

```
Output of x86-64 gcc 11.2 (Compiler #3)
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:11:17: warning: conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'} may change value [-Wconversion]
   11 |     uint8_t k = a + b + c;
      |                 ^
Compiler returned: 0
```

This does not happen when adding two unsigned chars, i.e. `a + b`, for example.
It happens when using any combination of arithmetic operations between more than three unsigned chars.
And it does not happen with clang version 12.0.1.

Why does `a + b + c`, for example, result in an `int` that must be cast to `uint8_t` before assigning to `k` to supress the warning?

Comment: Perhaps helpful: [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: A guess: with three terms, the result of `a + b` has type `int`, and so the second `+` is an expression of the form `int + uint8_t`.  Perhaps the compiler always warns about `int + uint8_t` but never about `uint8_t + uint8_t`.

Comment: FWIW, gcc bugzilla finds 90+ active bugs that mention `-Wconversion`. Caveat emptor.

Comment: Tortellini Teusday, Could use `uint8_t k = ( uint8_t) (a + b + c);` to quiet such warnings.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes I do get that this is one way to do it, that's stated in the last sentence of the question. The question was more about why this triggers the warning and `a+b` for example does not

Comment: gcc doesn't put much effort into detecting false positives with `-Wconversion`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to how integer promotion works in C. The C standard specifies that if an `int` can hold the values of the types of `a` and `b` - then they are converted to `int` for the operation.

This is the case with `uint8_t` and `int`.

Quote from the standard (6.3.1.1):

> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows
>
> ...
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is
> converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.
> These are called the integer promotions. 48) All other types are
> unchanged by the integer promotions

---

In old versions of gcc - this warning **was** triggered by addition of two operands like `a + b`. In GCC 10 this was removed by default from `-Wconversion`, but this warning is available with `-Warth-conversion`. From the [GCC 10 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html):

> -Warith-conversion re-enables warnings from -Wconversion, -Wfloat-conversion, and -Wsign-conversion that are now off by default for an expression where the result of an arithmetic operation will not
> fit in the target type due to promotion, but the operands of the
> expression do fit in the target type.

i.e. since GCC 10 the reason `a + b` doesn't trigger a warning with `-Wconversion` is that both of the operands of the express are `uint8_t`, which do fit in the target type (`int`).

With `a + b + c` this is no longer the case, because `a + b` becomes an `int`, and the expression becomes `int + uint8_t` - which seems to not satisfy the criteria that "the operands of the expression do fit in the target type".

Comment: Newer gcc versions (10 and up) don't warn if you only add two though.

Comment: You seem to have an older version of gcc than OP does.  I get a warning only for GCC before version 10, but not for later versions.  https://godbolt.org/z/8P4aTdx9T

Comment: Interesting - is this not then nonconformant (as a warning) as per the standard? `uint8_t + uint8_t` will then be (when promoted to `int`s) - `int + int` - which is an `int` - which should trigger the conversion warning

Comment: I'm using GCC 11.2 and it does _not_ warn when adding only two

Comment: Yes, Compiler Explorer shows that the warning behavior changed between gcc 9.4 and 10.1..

Comment: The behavior indeed seems to have changed with the GCC 10 release, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Re “The C standard specifies that if an `int` can hold the values in `a` and `b` - then they are converted to `int` for the operation”: The values in `a` and `b` are irrelevant. The rules is that if an `int` can represent all the values that the type of `a` can represent, then it is converted to an `int`, and similarly for `b`. E.g., if we had `int128_t a = 1;` and `uint128_t b = 3;`, then your expression of the rule would have `a` and `b` each converted to an `int`, since an `int` can represent 1 and 3. But they are not (when `int` is only 32 bits).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant the types of `a` and `b` but you're right that this isn't 100% clear, I'll fix this